# Is it possible to deploy SSL catch-all certificate on different servers?

Tags: web-server, ssl-certificate

I have a "catch-all certificate" that I would like to use on another server that resides in another VM. How can I achieve this? I haven't seen any docs that explain otherwise.

Comment: Copy the private key and certificate to the other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to export the certificate with its private key and then import it on the other server.

How you do that depends entirely on the OS / Webserver that you use.

Also, make sure that your certificate provider allows the installation and usage on multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks. The webservers are different but the OS is the same.